# My app wasn't able to rerender on installation startup 'singleton' that I have created ONLY when I generate the apk file through eam build

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, expo-sqlite

My app wasn't able to rerender on installation startup 'singleton' that I have created ONLY when I generate the apk file through eam build.

It is working when I use `expo-go` I have click on one of the other button (this case, my own create exercise button) for it to force rerender again. this create button sets a useState to render a 'Modal'

I am really tired of working on this. Hope there is some suggestions for this bug.

**App.tsx**

```
import {
  Alert, LogBox
} from 'react-native'
import { ExercisesScreen } from './screens/ExercisesScreen'
import { SettingsScreen } from './screens/SettingsScreen'
import { PlanScreen } from './screens/ScheduleScreen'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import {
  init, resetTables, createScheduledItem, deleteScheduledItem, updateScheduledItem,
  createExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship, createExercise,
  deleteExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship, deleteExercise, updateExercise,
  retrieveExerciseMajorMuscleRelationships, retrieveMajorMuscles,
  retrieveScheduledItems, retrieveExercises, deleteFromExerciseAndScheduledItem
} from './dbhandler'
import {
  ButtonSetProps, ContextProps, DialogState, Exercise, ExerciseState,
  MajorMuscle, PushPullEnum, ScheduledItemState
} from './types'
import { ScheduledItem } from './types'
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast'
import Colors from './constants/Colors'
import { DateData } from 'react-native-calendars'
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons, } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import _default from 'babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata'
import { ScheduleDialog } from './screens/ScheduleDialog'
import { ExerciseDialog } from './screens/ExerciseDialog'
import { styles } from './constants/styles'
import { SelectDateDialog } from './screens/SelectDateDialog'
import { StorageAccessFramework } from 'expo-file-system'
import {
  ExerciseInformationText, EditExerciseText,
  CreateExerciseText, ScheduledItemInformation,
  EditScheduledItemText, DuplicateScheduledItemText, CreateScheduledItemText
} from './constants/strings'
import {
  initialExerciseState, initialScheduledItemState, initialMajorMuscles,
  initialEmm, initialDialogState, initialScheduledItem, ExerciseScreenContext,
  ScheduledItemContext, SettingsScreenContext
} from './constants/initialValues'
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker'
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Require cycle:'])
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default function App() {
  const [exerciseState, setExerciseState] = useState<ExerciseState>(initialExerciseState)
  const [scheduledItemState, setScheduledItemState] =
    useState<ScheduledItemState>(initialScheduledItemState)
  const [dialogState, SetDialogState] = useState<DialogState>(initialDialogState)
  const [emm, setEmm] = useState(initialEmm)

  const [dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected, setDropDownMajorMuscleValues] = useState([""])
  const [dropDownExNameSelected, setDropDownExNameSelected] = useState("")
  const [dropDownPushPullSelected, setDropDownPushPullSelected] = useState(PushPullEnum.Push)

  function handlePlanHeader(date: DateData) {
    const s: string = ("Plan " + date.day + "-" + date.month + "-" + date.year)
    SetDialogState({ ...dialogState, planHeader: s })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    let tempExercises: Exercise[]
    if (exerciseState.exercises[0] != undefined)
      if (exerciseState.exercises[0].name == ""
        || exerciseState.exercises.length <= 0)
        retrieveExercises((_, r) => {
          tempExercises = r.rows._array
          tempExercises.forEach(ex => ex.major_muscles = initialMajorMuscles)
          if (scheduledItemState.scheduledItems[0] != undefined)
            if (scheduledItemState.scheduledItems[0].exercise
              == initialExerciseState.aExercise)
              retrieveScheduledItems(
                (_, results) => {
                  const tempScheduledItems: ScheduledItem[] = results.rows._array
                  const a = results.rows._array.slice()
                  tempScheduledItems.forEach((ms, index) => {
                    ms.date = JSON.parse(ms.date.toString())
                    const t = tempExercises.find(ex => ex.name == a[index].exercise)
                    tempScheduledItems[index].exercise = t!
                  })
                  setScheduledItemState({
                    ...scheduledItemState,
                    scheduledItems: tempScheduledItems,
                    filteredScheduledItems: tempScheduledItems
                  })
                })
          setExerciseState({
            ...exerciseState, exercises: tempExercises,
            filteredExercises: tempExercises
          })
        })

    if (exerciseState.majorMuscles[0] == initialMajorMuscles[0]) {
      retrieveMajorMuscles(
        (_, results) => setExerciseState({
          ...exerciseState,
          majorMuscles: results.rows._array
        }))
    }
    if (emm[0] == initialEmm[0])
      retrieveExerciseMajorMuscleRelationships(
        (_, results) => setEmm(results.rows._array))
    if (exerciseState.majorMuscles.length > 1
      && exerciseState.exercises.length > 1
      && emm.length > 1) {
      emm.forEach(x => {
        const ex: Exercise =
          exerciseState.exercises.find(e => e.name == x.exercise_name)!
        const mm2: MajorMuscle = exerciseState
          .majorMuscles
          .find(mm => mm.name == x.major_muscle_name)!
        if (ex == undefined || mm2 == undefined) return
        if (ex.major_muscles == initialMajorMuscles)
          ex.major_muscles = [mm2!]
        else if (!ex.major_muscles.find(x => x.name == mm2.name))
          ex.major_muscles.push(mm2!)
      })
    }
  }, [scheduledItemState, exerciseState, emm])
  init()

  let textInputStyle, numberInputStyle
  if (dialogState.isEditable) {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputEditable
    numberInputStyle = styles.numberInputEditable
  } else {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputViewOnly
    numberInputStyle = styles.numberInputViewOnly
  }

  const handleResetDB = () => {
    resetTables()
    setExerciseState(initialExerciseState)
    setScheduledItemState(initialScheduledItemState)
    SetDialogState(initialDialogState)
    setEmm(initialEmm)
  }

  //Android only export and import
  async function handleExport() {
    const exportData = {
      exercises: exerciseState.exercises,
      scheduledItems: scheduledItemState.scheduledItems
    }
    const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync()
    if (!permissions.granted) return
    let uri = await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(
      permissions.directoryUri, "GymTracker backup", "application/json"
    )
    await StorageAccessFramework.writeAsStringAsync(uri, JSON.stringify(exportData))
    Alert.alert("", `The backup data is now saved in the approved folder as `
      + `GymTracker backup.json`
      + `\nNote: if there is multiple backups, it will be numbered.`,
      [{
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => { },
        style: "cancel"
      }],
      { cancelable: true }
    )

  }

  async function handleImport() {
    Toast.show("Please grant folder permissions.")
    const permissions =
      await StorageAccessFramework
        .requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync()
    if (!permissions.granted) return
    Toast.show("Please choose the correct json file")
    let documentResult: DocumentPicker.DocumentResult =
      await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ type: 'application/json' })
    if (documentResult.type == 'cancel') return

    const data = JSON.parse(
      await StorageAccessFramework
        .readAsStringAsync(documentResult.uri))
    console.log(data)
    if (!('exercises' in data) || !('scheduledItems' in data)) {
      Toast.show("The data does not have the correct format")
      return
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(data.exercises)
      || !Array.isArray(data.scheduledItems)) {
      Toast.show("The data does not have the correct format")
      return
    }
    deleteFromExerciseAndScheduledItem()
    setExerciseState({
      ...exerciseState,
      exercises: data.exercises,
      filteredExercises: data.exercises
    })
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState,
      scheduledItems: data.scheduledItems,
      filteredScheduledItems: data.scheduledItems
    })
    data.exercises.forEach((ex: Exercise) => createExercise(ex))
    console.log(scheduledItemState.scheduledItems)
    data
      .scheduledItems
      .forEach((si: ScheduledItem) => createScheduledItem(si))
  }

  function cancelDialog() {
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isExDialogVisible: false,
      isCalendarDialogVisible: false,
      isPlanDialogVisible: false
    })
  }

  // Exercises Functions:
  //renders
  const renderExerciseDialogForViewing = (exercise: Exercise) => {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputViewOnly
    setExerciseState({
      ...exerciseState,
      aExercise: exercise,
      oldExerciseName: exercise.name
    })
    const names: string[] = []
    exercise.major_muscles.forEach(mm => names.push(mm.name))
    setDropDownMajorMuscleValues(names)
    setDropDownPushPullSelected(exercise.push_or_pull)
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isExDialogVisible: true, openPushPullDropDown: false,
      dialogText: ExerciseInformationText,
      isEditable: false, isDropDownOpen: false,
    })
  }

  const renderExerciseDialogForEdit = () => {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputEditable
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isEditable: true,
      dialogText: EditExerciseText,
      isDropDownOpen: false,
      openPushPullDropDown: false
    })
  }

  const renderExerciseDialogForCreate = () => {
    setExerciseState({
      ...exerciseState, aExercise:
        initialExerciseState.aExercise
    })
    setDropDownMajorMuscleValues([])
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputEditable
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isExDialogVisible: true, openPushPullDropDown: false,
      dialogText: CreateExerciseText, isEditable: true, isDropDownOpen: false
    })
    setDropDownPushPullSelected(PushPullEnum.Push)
  }

  //db
  const commonExercisesCRUD = (es: Exercise[]) => {
    setExerciseState({
      ...exerciseState, exercises: [...es],
      filteredExercises: [...es],
      filteredExerciseKeyword: ""
    })
    cancelDialog()
  }

  const deleteExerciseConfirmation = (exercise: Exercise) => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Confirmation",
      "Are you sure you want to delete this exercise?",
      [{
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => deleteExerciseWithStateUpdate(exercise)
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        onPress: () => renderExerciseDialogForViewing(exercise)
      }],//warning, recursive-
      { cancelable: true }
    )
  }

  const deleteExerciseWithStateUpdate = (exercise: Exercise) => {
    const selected: MajorMuscle[] = exerciseState.majorMuscles.filter(
      x => dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected.includes(x.name))
    selected.forEach(
      x => deleteExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship(exercise.name, x.name))
    deleteExercise(exercise.name, () => {
      const deletedName = exercise.name
      const es: Exercise[] = exerciseState.exercises.slice()
      es.forEach((currentExercise, i) => {
        if (currentExercise.name == deletedName) {
          es.splice(i, 1)
          return
        }
      })
      //correct way of removing element from a array for me. Not using delete keyword which leaves a undefined space
      Toast.show("The exercise " + deletedName + " has is deleted.")
      commonExercisesCRUD(es)
    })
  }

  const updateExerciseWithStateUpdate = () => {
    const aExercise = exerciseState.aExercise
    if (aExercise.name.trim() == "") {
      Toast.show("name cannot be empty")
      return
    }
    const oldExerciseName = exerciseState.oldExerciseName
    const pushPullDropDownValue = dropDownPushPullSelected
    const selected: MajorMuscle[] = exerciseState.majorMuscles.filter(
      x => dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected.includes(x.name))
    const toBeCreated: MajorMuscle[] = selected.filter(
      x => !aExercise.major_muscles.find(t => t.name == x.name))
    const toBeDeleted: MajorMuscle[] = aExercise.major_muscles.filter(
      x => !selected.find(t => t.name == x.name))
    toBeCreated.forEach(
      x => createExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship(aExercise.name, x.name))
    toBeDeleted.forEach(
      x => deleteExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship(aExercise.name, x.name))
    aExercise.push_or_pull = pushPullDropDownValue
    updateExercise(aExercise, oldExerciseName,
      () => {
        const exerciseToBeUpdated: Exercise = {
          name: aExercise.name, description: aExercise.description,
          imagesJson: aExercise.imagesJson,
          major_muscles: selected, push_or_pull: dropDownPushPullSelected
        }
        const es: Exercise[] = exerciseState.exercises.slice()
        es.forEach((currentExercise, i) => {
          if (currentExercise.name == oldExerciseName) {
            es.splice(i, 1, exerciseToBeUpdated)
            return
          }
        })
        commonExercisesCRUD(es)
        Toast.show("The exercise is updated.")
      })
  }

  function createExerciseWithStateUpdate() {
    const aExercise = exerciseState.aExercise
    if (aExercise.name == "") {
      Toast.show("name cannot be empty")
      return
    }
    const selected: MajorMuscle[] = exerciseState.majorMuscles.filter(
      x => dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected.includes(x.name))
    selected.forEach(
      x => createExerciseMajorMuscleRelationship(aExercise.name, x.name))

    aExercise.push_or_pull = dropDownPushPullSelected
    console.log(aExercise.push_or_pull)
    createExercise(aExercise, (_, result) => {
      const es: Exercise[] = exerciseState.exercises.slice()
      es.push({
        name: aExercise.name, description: aExercise.description,
        imagesJson: aExercise.imagesJson, major_muscles: selected,
        push_or_pull: dropDownPushPullSelected
      })
      commonExercisesCRUD(es)
      Toast.show("The exercise " + aExercise.name + " is created.")
    })
  }

  function handleFilterExercises(keyword: string) {
    console.log("handleFilterExercises")
    setExerciseState({
      ...exerciseState,
      filteredExercises:
        exerciseState.exercises.filter(e => (
          e.name.includes(keyword)
          || e.major_muscles.filter(
            mm => mm.name.includes(keyword)
          ).length > 0
          || e.description.includes(keyword)
        )),
      filteredExerciseKeyword: keyword
    })
  }



  //Scheduled Item Functions: 
  //renders:
  function renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing(scheduledItem: ScheduledItem) {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputViewOnly
    numberInputStyle = styles.numberInputViewOnly
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState,
      aScheduledItem: scheduledItem
    })
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isEditable: false, dialogText: ScheduledItemInformation,
      isExDialogVisible: false, openPushPullDropDown: false,
      isPlanDialogVisible: true
    })
    setDropDownExNameSelected(scheduledItem.exercise.name)
  }

  function commonLogicForScheduledItemEditAndDuplication(dialogText: string) {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputEditable
    setScheduledItemState({ ...scheduledItemState, })
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState, isEditable: true,
      isDropDownOpen: false, dialogText: dialogText
    })
    setDropDownExNameSelected(scheduledItemState.aScheduledItem.exercise.name)
  }

  function renderScheduledItemDialogForCreate() {
    textInputStyle = styles.textInputEditable
    numberInputStyle = styles.numberInputEditable
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState,
      aScheduledItem: initialScheduledItem[0]
    })
    SetDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      isEditable: true, dialogText: CreateScheduledItemText,
      isPlanDialogVisible: true, isDropDownOpen: false,
    })
    setDropDownExNameSelected(exerciseState.exercises[0].name)
    const parts: string[] = dialogState.planHeader.split(" ")[1].split("-")
    const monthNumber: number = Number(parts[1])
    const month: string = monthNumber < 10
      ? "0" + monthNumber.toString()
      : monthNumber.toString()
    const day: string = Number(parts[0]) < 10 ? "0" + parts[0] : parts[0]
    const date: DateData = {
      year: Number(parts[2]), month: monthNumber,
      day: Number(parts[0]), timestamp: 0,
      dateString: parts[2] + "-" + month + "-" + day
    }
    const aScheduledItem = initialScheduledItem[0]
    aScheduledItem.date = date
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState,
      aScheduledItem: { ...aScheduledItem }
    })
  }

  //db:
  function commonScheduledItemCRUD(si: ScheduledItem[]) {
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState, scheduledItems: [...si],
      filteredScheduledItems: [...si],
      selectedScheduledItems: [],
      isMovingScheduledItems: false
    })
    cancelDialog()
  }

  const deleteScheduledItemConfirmation = (ms: ScheduledItem) => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Confirmation",
      "Are you sure you want to delete this scheduled item?",
      [{ text: "Yes", onPress: () => deleteScheduledItemWithStateUpdate(ms.id) },
      { text: "No", onPress: () => renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing(ms) }],//warning, recursive
      { cancelable: true }
    )
  }

  const deleteScheduledItemWithStateUpdate = (id: number) => {
    deleteScheduledItem(id, () => {
      const si = scheduledItemState.scheduledItems.slice()
      si.forEach((ms1, i) => {
        if (ms1.id == id) {
          si.splice(i, 1)
          return
        }
      }) //correct way of removing element from a array for me. Not using delete keyword which leaves a undefined space
      Toast.show("The scheduled item is deleted.")
      commonScheduledItemCRUD(si)
    })
  }

  const updateScheduledItemWithStateUpdate = () => {
    const aScheduledItem = scheduledItemState.aScheduledItem
    if (dropDownExNameSelected == undefined || dropDownExNameSelected == "") {
      Toast.show("exercise must be selected")
      return
    }
    const theexercise = exerciseState.exercises.filter((e, i, a) => {
      if (e.name == dropDownExNameSelected) return e
    })[0]
    updateScheduledItem(aScheduledItem,
      (_, result) => {
        const toBeUpdated: ScheduledItem = {
          id: aScheduledItem.id, exercise: theexercise, reps: aScheduledItem.reps,
          percent_complete: aScheduledItem.percent_complete, sets: aScheduledItem.sets,
          duration_in_seconds: aScheduledItem.duration_in_seconds,
          weight: aScheduledItem.weight, notes: aScheduledItem.notes,
          date: aScheduledItem.date
        }
        const ms: ScheduledItem[] = scheduledItemState.scheduledItems.slice()
        ms.forEach((currentScheduledItem, i) => {
          if (currentScheduledItem.id == aScheduledItem.id) {
            ms.splice(i, 1, toBeUpdated)
            return
          }
        })
        commonScheduledItemCRUD(ms)
        Toast.show("The major set is updated.")
      },
    )
  }

  function createScheduledItemWithStateUpdate() {
    const aScheduledItem = scheduledItemState.aScheduledItem
    exerciseState.exercises.forEach(e => {
      if (e.name == dropDownExNameSelected) {
        aScheduledItem.exercise = e
        return
      }
    })
    createScheduledItem(aScheduledItem,
      (_, r) => {
        const tempScheduledItem = { ...aScheduledItem }
        tempScheduledItem.id = r.insertId!
        tempScheduledItem.date = aScheduledItem.date
        tempScheduledItem.duration_in_seconds = aScheduledItem.duration_in_seconds
        const m = scheduledItemState.scheduledItems.slice()
        m.push(tempScheduledItem)
        commonScheduledItemCRUD(m)
        Toast.show("Scheduled item created.")
      })
  }

  function handleFilterScheduledItem(keyword: string) {
    console.log("here")
    const filtered = scheduledItemState.scheduledItems.filter(si => {
      const sec = si.duration_in_seconds % 60
      const min = Math.floor(si.duration_in_seconds / 60)
      return ((si.percent_complete.toString() + "%").includes(keyword)
        || si.id.toString().includes(keyword)
        || (si.weight.toString() + "kg").includes(keyword)
        || (si.sets.toString() + "x" + si.reps.toString()).includes(keyword)
        || (min + " minutes").includes(keyword)
        || (sec + " seconds").includes(keyword)
        || si.exercise.name.includes(keyword)
        || si.exercise.major_muscles.filter(
          si => si.name.includes(keyword)
        ).length > 0
      )
    }
    )
    setScheduledItemState({
      ...scheduledItemState,
      filteredScheduledItems: filtered,
      filteredScheduledItemKeyword: keyword
    })
  }
  const buttonsSetProps: ButtonSetProps = {
    cancelDialog: cancelDialog,
    deleteScheduledItemConfirmation: deleteScheduledItemConfirmation,
    deleteExerciseConfirmation: deleteExerciseConfirmation,
    createExerciseWithStateUpdate: createExerciseWithStateUpdate,
    updateExerciseWithStateUpdate: updateExerciseWithStateUpdate,
    createScheduledItemWithStateUpdate: createScheduledItemWithStateUpdate,
    updateScheduledItemWithStateUpdate: updateScheduledItemWithStateUpdate,
    renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing: renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing,
    renderScheduledItemDialogForDuplication:
      () => commonLogicForScheduledItemEditAndDuplication(DuplicateScheduledItemText),
    renderScheduledItemDialogForEdit:
      () => commonLogicForScheduledItemEditAndDuplication(EditScheduledItemText),
    renderExerciseDialogForEdit: renderExerciseDialogForEdit,
    renderExerciseDialogForViewing: renderExerciseDialogForViewing,
  }

  const contextProps: ContextProps = {
    renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing: renderScheduledItemDialogForViewing,
    renderScheduledItemDialogForCreate: renderScheduledItemDialogForCreate,
    renderExerciseDialogForCreate: renderExerciseDialogForCreate,
    renderExerciseDialogForViewing: renderExerciseDialogForViewing,

    handleFilterScheduledItem: handleFilterScheduledItem,
    handlePlanHeader: handlePlanHeader,
    handleFilterExercises: handleFilterExercises,

    commonScheduledItemCRUD: commonScheduledItemCRUD,

    scheduledItemState: scheduledItemState,
    dialogState: dialogState,
    exerciseState: exerciseState,

    setDialogState: SetDialogState,
    setScheduledItemState: setScheduledItemState,
    setExerciseState: setExerciseState,
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <ScheduleDialog
          dialogState={dialogState}
          exerciseState={exerciseState}
          scheduledItemState={scheduledItemState}
          dropDownExNameSelected={dropDownExNameSelected}

          setScheduledItemState={setScheduledItemState}
          setDialogState={SetDialogState}
          setDropDownExNameSelected={setDropDownExNameSelected}

          createExerciseWithStateUpdate={createExerciseWithStateUpdate}
          updateExerciseWithStateUpdate={updateExerciseWithStateUpdate}
          buttonsSetProps={buttonsSetProps}
        />
        <ExerciseDialog
          exerciseState={exerciseState}
          dialogState={dialogState}
          scheduledItemState={scheduledItemState}
          majorMuscles={exerciseState.majorMuscles}
          dropDownPushPullSelected={dropDownPushPullSelected}
          dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected={dropDownMajorMuscleNameSelected}

          setDropDownPushPullSelected={setDropDownPushPullSelected}
          setDialogState={SetDialogState}
          setExerciseState={setExerciseState}
          setMajorMuscleValues={setDropDownMajorMuscleValues}

          buttonsSetProps={buttonsSetProps}
        />
        <SelectDateDialog
          scheduledItemState={scheduledItemState}
          dialogState={dialogState}

          setScheduledItemState={setScheduledItemState}
          setDialogState={SetDialogState}

          commonScheduledItemCRUD={commonScheduledItemCRUD}
          buttonsSetProps={buttonsSetProps}
        />
        <SettingsScreenContext.Provider value={{
          handleResetDB: handleResetDB,
          handleExport: handleExport,
          handleImport: handleImport
        }}>
          <ExerciseScreenContext.Provider value={{ contextProps: contextProps }}>
            <ScheduledItemContext.Provider value={{ contextProps: contextProps }}>
              <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions={({ route }) =>
                ({
                  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    let iconName: any
                    switch (route.name) {
                      case 'Plan':
                        iconName = focused ? 'clipboard-list' : 'clipboard-list-outline'
                        return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                      case 'Exercises':
                        iconName = focused ? 'arm-flex' : 'arm-flex-outline'
                        return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                      case 'Settings':
                        iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline'
                        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                    }
                  },
                  tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.light.tint
                })
                }>
                <Tab.Screen
                  options={{ headerTitle: dialogState.planHeader }}
                  name="Plan" component={PlanScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Exercises" component={ExercisesScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
              </Tab.Navigator>
            </ScheduledItemContext.Provider>
          </ExerciseScreenContext.Provider>
        </SettingsScreenContext.Provider>
      </NavigationContainer >
    </>
  )
}
```

**ExerciseScreen.tsx**

```
import React from "react"
import { FlatList, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { ExerciseScreenContext } from '../constants/initialValues'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import layoutConstants from '../constants/Layout'
import { Exercise } from "../types"
import Layout from "../constants/Layout"
import Colors from "../constants/Colors"
import { TextInput } from "react-native"
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { styles } from "../constants/styles"

function ExercisesScreen() {
  let c = useContext(ExerciseScreenContext)
  let filteredExercises: Exercise[] = c.contextProps.exerciseState.filteredExercises
  let filteredKeyword: string = c.contextProps.exerciseState.filteredExerciseKeyword
  let handleSelected: Function = c.contextProps.renderExerciseDialogForViewing
  let handleShowCreate: Function = c.contextProps.renderExerciseDialogForCreate
  let handleFilterExercises: Function = c.contextProps.handleFilterExercises
  return (
    <View style={{
      flexDirection: "column", flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'flex-start',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }}>
      <FlatList
        style={{ width: '100%', transform: [{ rotateX: "180deg" }], }}
        data={filteredExercises}
        initialNumToRender={15}
        renderItem={
          ({ item }) =>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{
              alignItems: "flex-start",
              padding: layoutConstants.defaultMargin,
            }}
              onPress={() => handleSelected(item)}
            >
              <Text style={{
                transform: [{ rotateX: "180deg" }],
                fontSize: layoutConstants.defaultFontSize
              }}>
                {item.name}
              </Text >
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.filterExercisesTextInput}
        placeholder="Type here to filter exercises..."
        onChange={text => handleFilterExercises(text.nativeEvent.text)}
        value={filteredKeyword}
      />
      <View style={{ bottom: 20, end: 20, position: 'absolute' }}>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            ...styles.planScreenPressable,
            backgroundColor: Colors.light.tint,
          }}
          onPress={() => handleShowCreate()}
        >
          <Ionicons style={{ bottom: "-5%", right: "-10%" }}
            name="add-outline"
            size={Layout.defaultMargin + 40} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export { ExercisesScreen }
```

Edit:

Link to my repo
https://github.com/themissingCRAM/GymTracker

I guess i am not very clear in my question either the list of exercises should be there on my ExerciseScreen on startup but it isn't when I use my apk version only.

And my apologies, I am new to React and RN.

Comment: could you also show the return part in the app?

Comment: https://github.com/themissingCRAM/GymTracker/blob/master/App.tsx
https://github.com/themissingCRAM/GymTracker/blob/master/screens/ExercisesScreen.tsx I guess i am not very clear in my question either the list of exercises should be there on startup but it isn't. I feel embarrassed to show my codes haha.